# Прямая речь или диалог?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, прямая-речь, диалог

Как бы вы оформили такой текст? Другие персонажи не отвечают. Значит, в форме диалога не стоит? А как тогда оформить фразу, которую персонаж хотел сказать? Кавычки внутри кавычек или вообще без них?

– Ко… ко… – он набрал воздуха в грудь, чтобы сказать: «Ко-фе, что ли, сегодня выпить?», – и попробовал снова. – Ко…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** *— Ко… ко… — **о**н набрал воздуха в грудь...*
Если после прямой речи начинается самостоятельное предложение (то есть слов говорения нет), то слова автора пишутся с заглавной буквы. Правильно:
*— Ко… ко… — **О**н набрал воздуха в грудь...*

**2.** *...чтобы сказать: «Ко-фе, что ли, сегодня **выпить?»,** — и попробовал снова...*
Если прямая речь заканчивается вопросительным знаком, то запятая после закрывающих кавычек не ставится. Правильно:
*...чтобы сказать: «Ко-фе, что ли, сегодня **выпить?»** — и попробовал снова...*

**3.** *...и попробовал **снова.** — Ко…*
Если слова автора заканчиваются глаголом со значением высказывания, то после него ставится двоеточие и тире [и попробовал снова сказать, произнести]. Правильно:
*...и попробовал **снова:** — Ко…*

**4.** Слова, которые кто-то собирался сказать (Ко-фе, что ли, сегодня выпить?), думаю, лучше ввести в состав слов автора на правах члена предложения.
Тогда получится вот такая прямая речь, оформленная в один абзац:

*— Ко... ко... — Он набрал воздуха в грудь, чтобы сказать «Ко-фе, что ли, сегодня выпить?»,  и попробовал снова: — Ко...*

[Знаки препинания при прямой речи](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154#pp154)

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!